# Reading a value from database only once VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a VB.NET method, which connects to a database and reads the value.
And this value is used multiple times in multiple places.
The method looks like below:

```
Public Function IsConfigurationEnabled() As Integer

    Dim IsEnabled As Integer
    Dim sqlText As String
    sqlText = "select value from [dbo].[Settings] where Configuration='XXX'"
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=True"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, connection)
        IsEnabled = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        cmd.Dispose()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        AuditTrail(vbLogEventTypeError, "IsConfigurationEnabled :Error opening SQL Connection ")
    End Try
    Return IsEnabled
End Function
```

I want to connect to database only once.
As the value in database never changes (or changes rarely).
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Then you will have to store this value somewhere, maybe in some singleton or static property? That may depend on the application type (in a web app, usually a static value isn't the right choice)

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. ADO.NET uses connection pooling so the cost of opening / closing the connection over and over is not too much of a problem see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-pooling

Comment: `connect to db only once.` so don't call the method multiple times. Store the result in a field or property and reuse it. BTW this method is *extremely* buggy. It returns the wrong type (integer instead of boolean) In case of error it leaks the connection, maintains any locks on the table *and* returns a bogus value, `0`. Remove the `try/catch` block and use `Using` when declaring the connection to ensure it's closed even in case of errors. *Don't* hide the exception either. A missing database doesn't mean a disabled setting. It means the database is down

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I will do this sir. I appreciate your excellent observational skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the return value in the calling code is probably the best option. However, you can also use **lazy initialization** as follows.

```
Public Function IsConfigurationEnabled() As Integer
  Static isEnabled? As Integer
  If isEnabled.HasValue Then
    Return isEnabled.Value
  End If
  Dim sqlText As String = "select value from [dbo].[Settings] where Configuration='XXdX'"
  Using connection = New SqlConnection()
    connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Junk;Integrated Security=True"
    Try
      connection.Open()
      Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, connection)
        isEnabled = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
      End Using
      connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
      AuditTrail(vbLogEventTypeError, "IsConfigurationEnabled :Error opening SQL Connection ")
    End Try
  End Using
  Return IsEnabled
End Function
```

It would be controversial to use the above code in a real project, but I hope it is instructive.

Comment: I liked this approach a lot :) Can I know the reasons Y this is controversial ?

Comment: One problem is that the connection string is hardcoded, instead of gotten from a config

Comment: I think this approach is a bit controversial for the following reasons: 1. the static variable `isEnabled` stays around after the scope it is in is exited, 2. the method has a side-effect, and appears idempotent but isn't - for example, you might get unpredictable crashes that only happen when the routine is called the first time 3. you need to restart the program to reload the value - if the value in the database changes , calling this routine won't get the new value.

That said, I used to looove this pattern :D